# How can I syncronize android time with machine via ADB

Tags: sync, adb, shell, date-and-time

How can I update android time via ADB?

I know I can run this comand via windows cmd:

```
adb shell date -s 20140414.130000
```

But I need to synchronize the time with my windows machine.

Is this possible to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for this by using the ***perl***.

I created this perl script, which sends the current date with the correct format to the android device via adb:

```
use Time::localtime;
$_=localtime;
system'adb','shell','date -s',sprintf("%04d%02d%02d.%02d%02d%02d",$_->year+1900,$_->mon+1,$_->mday,$_->hour,$_->min,$_->sec)
```

Then I just need to open `cmd` and run this:

```
perl < clock.pl
```